# Confused with setting up ML and DL on GPU

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu

My goal is to set up my PC for machine and deep learning through my GPU. I've read about all the different components however I can not connect the dots for what I need to do.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- GPU: Nvidia RTX 2070 Super
- Anaconda: 4.8.3

I've installed the nvidia-cuda-toolkit (10.1.243), but now what?

- How does this integrate with jupyter notebook?
- The 3 python modules I want to work with are:

  - turicreate - I've gotten this to run off CPU but not GPU
  - scikit-learn
  - tensorflow
  - matlab

I know cuDNN and pyCUDA fit in there somewhere.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - I have the experience limited to ubuntu 18.04 and 16.xx and python DL frameworks. But I hope some sugestions will be helpfull.

- If I were familiar with docker I would rather consider to use docker instead of setting-up everything from scratch. This approach is described in section about [tensorflow container](https://www.tensorflow.org/install)
- If you decided to setup all components yourself please see [this guideline](https://illya13.github.io/RL/tutorial/2020/04/26/installing-tensorflow-on-ubuntu-20.html)
  I used some contents from it for 18.04, succesfully.
- be carefull with automatic updates. After the configuration is finished and tested protect it from being overwritten with newest version of CUDAor TensorRT.

Answering one of your sub-questions - *How does this integrate with jupyter notebook?* - **it does not, becuase it is unneccesary**. CUDA library cooperates with a framework such as Tensorflow, not with the Jupyter. Jupyter is just an editor and execution controller on the server side.

Comment: Is docker compatible with anaconda?

Comment: On the basis of documentation, not my experience:
- in general yes. You can for example download docker image with anaconda from dockerhub [link](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3)
- with regards to Nvidia docker image - I don't know, (but I think you should be able to edit dockerfile and add anaconda)